# PHP - Generate XML request template out WSDL

Tags: php, xml, web-services, wsdl

I have web service descriptor like for example `http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/AWSECommerceService.wsdl`

However mine has over 800 methods and each of them may come with about 30 parameters so building XML requests manually would be a pain.

In .NET once WS provider is compiled the whole list of methods along with SOAP/HTTP samples and testing form is auto-generated.

Can anyone advise if there is similar solution that translates WSDL into XML queries also available in PHP?